# Objective-C, dispatch_queue_t blocking main thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, grand-central-dispatch

I've been having quite a bit of difficulty with a `dispatch_queue_t` operation that loads a very large file into memory blocking the main thread (spinning or spinlock) for whatever reason (probably because it's huge). I've tried everything imaginable to remedy the problem (such as the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6497743/1432710), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23599251), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13927198) + a dozen others) but no luck.

I've tried various methods to read the file such as `NSInputStream` (with buffers), `dataWithContentsOfFile` (NSDataReadingMapped), etc. and regardless once I do something such as the following the main thread beach balls for 4-5 seconds and then the operation continues normally in the background.

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{

        NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile options:NSDataReadingMapped error:nil];

});
```

I'm wondering how to avoid the big hit at the beginning of the operation so the main thread is not affected. I'm so confused as to why the main thread would be affected regardless since I am supposedly doing the entire operation in a background queue. thanks.

Comment: Put xcode at pause when main thread is blocked and look in stack what is blocking it.

Comment: @Cy-4AH: Well that's the thing, the `dataWithContentsOfFile` is what is blocking it for some reason.

Comment: Are you saying that if you follow @Cy-4AH's suggestion you can see the call to `dataWithContentsOfFile` on the main thread even though you apparently have dispatched it on another one? Or are you seeing something else which tells you this call is responsible for the main thread being blocked?

Comment: @CRD: When the "spinning" starts and the gui is frozen for several seconds the only thing Instruments Time Profiler shows is `_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread`, then right before the file is read it shows `_dispatch_call_block_and_release` followed by the function (which reads the file) which has `_block_invoke` shown next to it in the call tree. So to answer your question, I don't see that it is actually doing something to the main thread, although would a background thread spin-lock like that if it wasn't?

Comment: Could you just print stack trace of main thread when it's blocked?

Comment: @Cy-4AH: I actually found the issue, and resolved it. It was a problem with an `NSTask` that was causing it; there's another issue though now in relation to that which I'll post a different question about. Thanks guys.

Comment: @CRD: See comment directly above, thanks for your help.